# cyclic shift using d flip flop vhdl

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I am trying to design a  shiftier using d flip flop as a component.. 
The flip flop works fine.. but the shifter output remains undefined ,, how should I fix it? 
this is the shiftier code

```
entity cyclicSR is -- 3-bit cyclic shift register
 port (CLK: in bit; Qout: out bit_vector(1 to 3) ) ;
 end cyclicSR;
 architecture cyclicSR3 of cyclicSR is
 component DFF
 port (D, CLK: in bit; Q: out bit);
 end component;
 signal Q1, Q2, Q3: bit;
 begin
 FF1: DFF port map (Q3, CLK, Q1);
 FF2: DFF port map (Q1, CLK, Q2);
 FF3: DFF port map (Q2, CLK, Q3);
 Qout <= Q1&Q2&Q3;
 end cyclicSR3;
```

Should I assign a value to q3?? how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the problem is visible in your code example.

You need to provide an initial value or 'set' to at least one flipflop. Otherwise it happily shifts all zeros cyclically - the default value for type BIT.

Alternatively you could jam an input into say the first flip flop when all three are 0:

```
architecture jam of cyclicsr is

    component dff is
        port (
             d, clk: in  bit; 
             q:      out bit
        );
    end component;

     component or2 is 
         port (
             a:     in  bit;
             b:     in  bit;
             y:     out bit
         );
     end component;

     component nor3 is
         port (
             a:     in  bit;
             b:     in  bit;
             c:     in  bit;
             y:     out bit
         );
     end component;

     signal q1, q2, q3: bit;

     signal inp:        bit;   -- added
     signal all_zero:   bit;

begin

 ff1: dff port map (inp, clk, q1);  -- was q3
 ff2: dff port map (q1, clk, q2);
 ff3: dff port map (q2, clk, q3);

     qout <= q1 & q2 & q3;

orgate:
    or2 
        port map (
            a => all_zero,
            b => q3,
            y => inp
        );
allzero:
    nor3
        port map (
            a => q1,
            b => q2,
            c => q3,
            y => all_zero
        );

end architecture;
```

And that gives:

[image: cyclicsr_tb.png]

And note you can set any pattern you want with an initial value or with the a single inverter turn the shift register into a [Johnson counter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_counter#Johnson_and_Overbeck_counters).